# Bad font resulting in invisible text in email and elsewhere

Tags: catalina, font

Recently I started receiving emails with blank messages. If I reply-to those emails, select the text and change the font, the text shows up.

Via some experimenting I determined that Times Roman and Times Regular appear to be the problem. These are, I believe, system fonts. I'm running Catalina, all up to date.

I use Font Agent Pro to manage fonts. It doesn't report any problems.

How should I go about repairing this?

Comment: I wonder if it is the font *color* that they change? I have gotten a few of those and it ends up being fonts that are set to white, essentially making them invisible.

Comment: Which application? Mail.app? How do you 'select text' if 'it isn't there' (blank)? Which "experimenting" gave you the clue to Times & TNR "to be the problem"?

Comment: I hit reply to an email message. In the reply, the text is still blank. I select where the text should be, bring up the Fonts panel and choose another font like Arial. The text appears, in black. The clue was from placing the cursor in the area where the text was invisible and seeing that the font was Times Roman, then by trying other Times variants. Bold, italic, BI all work, as do all other fonts tested.